# Formation of peptide bond..?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

Proteins peptide bond is made by condensation process in which a molecule of water is released and according to this process it is not favorable in water systems than how peptide bond is formed by condensation in cytoplasm in the presence of water ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condensation is not done in water alone - the enzymatic function of the ribosome plays the essential part here. And in the active center of the ribosome where the formation of the peptide bond takes place, no water is present, only the growing peptide chain and the single amino acid (bound to the tRNA). See this schematic image from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28biology%29):

[image]

If you make x-ray crystallography, this looks like this (from [here](http://www.esrf.eu/UsersAndScience/Publications/Highlights/2006/SB/SB04)). You can see that the tRNA with the unbound amino acid is actually inside the ribosome and protected from the outside:

[image]